Enumerate within tabular
For the life of mine I cannot figure out how to get this to work, does someone know what is missing - the goal is to have  a bullet list within my tabular - the error I get  is "missing \item" which is not true
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{protocol}

\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\definecolor{Bright}{HTML}{58318f}
\definecolor{Green}{HTML}{319866}
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{111111}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{515c50}
\colorlet{heading}{Green}
\colorlet{accent}{Bright}
\colorlet{emphasis}{Black}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faSpinner}




\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
10‘ &    Begrüßung, Anwesenheit, Warm-Up Solo: Body + Bachata \\
5‘  &    Warm-Up Couples: frei, mit Ansagen, auch als Rueda  möglich \\
10‘ &    Wdh. Inhalte Vorheriger Stunde in geschlossenen Kursen: 
            durchgehen + zu Musik, Fragen klären \\
30‘ &    Neue Technik/Figur/Kombination:
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Ggf. zuerste Soloerklärung vor dem Spiegel 
\item  1x Vorzeigen 
\item In einzelne Teile/Vorübungen runterbrechen 
\item  Gezählt, Musik, Details verbessern → Mehrmals 
\item  Erklärungsebenen: Füße, Körper, Leading 
\item  Didaktische Reserve: Variationen 
\item  Methoden: „Bluetooth-Connection“, nur Ellenbogen, Switch, nur ein Arm (leadender Frame) 
\end{enumerate} \\
5‘  & Abschlussvideo \\
 \end{tabular}   
\end{table}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. You wrote, "the goal is to have a bullet list" -- so why are you employing an enumerate environment instead of an itemize environment? Please advise.

I think enumerate or itemize lists need p column type. See also How to use itemize in Table environment.

You can use a minipage environment in the tabular.   You have used \geometry command before loading the geometry package.  You have also not loaded xcolor or any other package for color.  I have fixed these. I am also getting other errors.  I don't know about the protocol class. Here is a modified version of your file.  You can play around with the minipage length.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{protocol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=9cm,marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{Bright}{HTML}{58318f}
\definecolor{Green}{HTML}{319866}
\definecolor{Black}{HTML}{111111}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{515c50}
\colorlet{heading}{Green}
\colorlet{accent}{Bright}
\colorlet{emphasis}{Black}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faSpinner}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabular}{cl}
            10‘ &    Begrüßung, Anwesenheit, Warm-Up Solo: Body + Bachata \\
            5‘  &    Warm-Up Couples: frei, mit Ansagen, auch als Rueda  möglich \\
            10‘ &    Wdh. Inhalte Vorheriger Stunde in geschlossenen Kursen: 
            durchgehen + zu Musik, Fragen klären \\
            30‘ &   \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm} Neue Technik/Figur/Kombination:
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item  Ggf. zuerste Soloerklärung vor dem Spiegel 
                \item  1x Vorzeigen 
                \item In einzelne Teile/Vorübungen runterbrechen 
                \item  Gezählt, Musik, Details verbessern → Mehrmals 
                \item  Erklärungsebenen: Füße, Körper, Leading 
                \item  Didaktische Reserve: Variationen 
                \item  Methoden: „Bluetooth-Connection“, nur Ellenbogen, Switch, nur ein Arm (leadender Frame) 
            \end{enumerate} \end{minipage}\\
            5‘  & Abschlussvideo \\
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}



Your question is already solved by comments and nice @S. Venkataraman answer (+1), actually similar ones has been asked many time before
Unfortunately your question as well the answer I can't test since I haven't protocol document class, however solution consider `article should work fine  also using it.
If you willing to use tabularray document class and enumitem packages for all lists in your document, than the following simple and short example may be of help in solving of your problem:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={1cm,9cm}, vmargin=1cm,
          marginparwidth=6.8cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,
          showframe}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[ c] X[l]},
             stretch=-1,%<--- remove extra space above and below lists
                        % with nosep option; doc p.51 tabularray
              measure = vbox,
              rowsep  = 3 pt
             }
10‘ &    Begrüßung, Anwesenheit, Warm-Up Solo: Body + Bachata           \\
 5‘ &    Warm-Up Couples: frei, mit Ansagen, auch als Rueda  möglich    \\
10‘ &    Wdh. Inhalte Vorheriger Stunde in geschlossenen Kursen:  
        durchgehen + zu Musik, Fragen klären                            \\
30‘ &   Neue Technik/Figur/Kombination:
        \begin{enumerate}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
    \item   Ggf. zuerste Soloerklärung vor dem Spiegel 
    \item   1x Vorzeigen 
    \item   In einzelne Teile/Vorübungen runterbrechen 
    \item   Gezählt, Musik, Details verbessern → Mehrmals 
    \item   Erklärungsebenen: Füße, Körper, Leading 
    \item   Didaktische Reserve: Variationen 
    \item   Methoden: „Bluetooth-Connection“, nur Ellenbogen, Switch, nur ein Arm (leadender Frame) 
        \end{enumerate}     \\
 5‘ & Abschlussvideo        \\
\end{tblr}   
    \end{table}
\end{document}

(in above MWE I left out all packages irrelevant to your problem)


Do you need a tabular? You can do it with tabularx, but why not simply an itemize list? There's no rule that imposes a tabular (or variation thereof) inside a table environment.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% likely loaded by protocol
\geometry{
  left=1cm,
  right=9cm,
  marginparwidth=6.8cm,
  marginparsep=1.2cm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1cm,
  showframe% just for debugging
}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % only ngerman
\usepackage[default]{lato}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
10‘
& Begrüßung, Anwesenheit, Warm-Up Solo: Body + Bachata \\
\addlinespace
5‘
& Warm-Up Couples: frei, mit Ansagen, auch als Rueda  möglich \\
\addlinespace
10‘
& Wdh. Inhalte Vorheriger Stunde in geschlossenen Kursen: 
   durchgehen + zu Musik, Fragen klären \\
\addlinespace
30‘
& Neue Technik/Figur/Kombination:
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item  Ggf. zuerste Soloerklärung vor dem Spiegel 
  \item  1x Vorzeigen 
  \item In einzelne Teile/Vorübungen runterbrechen 
  \item  Gezählt, Musik, Details verbessern → Mehrmals 
  \item  Erklärungsebenen: Füße, Körper, Leading 
  \item  Didaktische Reserve: Variationen 
  \item  Methoden: „Bluetooth-Connection“, nur Ellenbogen, Switch, nur ein Arm (leadender Frame) 
  \end{enumerate} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\addlinespace
5‘
& Abschlussvideo \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{itemize}[align=right]
\item[10‘] Begrüßung, Anwesenheit, Warm-Up Solo: Body + Bachata

\item[5‘] Warm-Up Couples: frei, mit Ansagen, auch als Rueda  möglich

\item[10‘] Wdh. Inhalte Vorheriger Stunde in geschlossenen Kursen: 
   durchgehen + zu Musik, Fragen klären

\item[30‘] Neue Technik/Figur/Kombination:
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item  Ggf. zuerste Soloerklärung vor dem Spiegel 
  \item  1x Vorzeigen 
  \item In einzelne Teile/Vorübungen runterbrechen 
  \item  Gezählt, Musik, Details verbessern → Mehrmals 
  \item  Erklärungsebenen: Füße, Körper, Leading 
  \item  Didaktische Reserve: Variationen 
  \item  Methoden: „Bluetooth-Connection“, nur Ellenbogen, Switch, nur ein Arm (leadender Frame) 
  \end{enumerate}

\item[5‘] Abschlussvideo
\end{itemize}

\end{table}

\end{document}


The rules around the image are produced by the showframe option and only show the margins of the text block.
Loading both german and ngerman makes little sense: the latter option is for conforming to the Neue Rechtschreibung, the former is for older conventions.
